# Number of paths in a grid

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

A common puzzle problem is to count the number of paths that start from the bottom-left-hand corner of a grid and end at the top-right hand corner, with the restriction that you can only move upwards or rightwards.

For example, for a 3 by 3 grid (as shown below), the total number of ways is $\binom{6}{3}=20$

If we modify the problem to allow the path to contain downwards and leftwards moves, but maintain a restriction that you cannot visit an intersection twice, what is a general solution for the number of possible paths?

(In the case of the 3 by 3 grid below, I enumerated the total paths with a computer program and got 210).

[image]

Comment: This is called "self-avoiding rook walk", see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Self-AvoidingWalk.html .

Comment: Is https://oeis.org/A007764 what you want?

Comment: I'm not convinced by your 3 by 3 grid giving 20 paths under restriction of moving up or right: I'd rather say 6 paths:

Comment: UURR URUR  URRU RRUU RURU RUUR and that's it. No? And https://oeis.org/A007764 contains a specific example for the non-intersecting rook paths as a(3)=12, not 210! (exclamation mark, not factorial). What's going on?

Comment: @Wouter, you are moving from one square to another, Vincent is moving from one vertex to another.

Comment: @WouterM. I'm now not sure that the number I generated was correct, it may have been an error in my code that i used to count the number of paths. Gerry - I think the oeis link you posted is exactly what I was looking for. Let me get back to my code and check it again.